# Объясните значение регулярок из кода

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нашел в коде обработку ключевых слов (слова через запятую)

```
$key_words=preg_replace("/(\s)+\,/",",",$key_words);
$key_words=preg_replace("/\,(\s)+/",",",$key_words);
$key_words=preg_replace("/(\,)+/",",",$key_words);
$key_words=preg_replace("/^\,+/","",$key_words);
$key_words=preg_replace("/(\,)+$/","",$key_words);
```

Не могу понять целесообразности данной обработки. Можете растолковать каждую?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `"/(\s)+\,/"` – поиск пробельных символов до запятой
- `"/\,(\s)+/"` – поиск пробельных символов после запятой
- `"/(\,)+/"` – поиск одной и больше подряд запятых
- `"/^\,+/"` – аналогично тому, что выше, но запятая должна быть в начале строки, а в шаблоне выше – в любом месте текста
- `"/(\,)+$/"` – поиск запятых (от одной и больше) и запятые обязательно должны быть до конца строки

Экранировать запятые, кстати, не нужно, в отличии от точек `.`. Да и группирование (например, `(\s)+`) выглядит странно. Мне кажется, по замыслу автора регулярок, должны все совпадения охватываться в группе: `(\s+)`.